# How do I set the value of a label in a Gridview's footer template?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, webforms

I have some labels on a gridview that I am trying to set the text to on page load. i fixed the "object reference error", however I have not figured out how to set the labels text dynamically. Here is what I tried:

```
protected string AutoDate, Website;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    BindData();
    pnlMainGrid.Visible = true;
    DateTime dtMyDate = DateTime.Now;
    AutoDate = Convert.ToString(dtMyDate);
    Website = "MySite";
    Label lblCreateDate = ((Label)gvMainView.FooterRow.FindControl("lblCreateDate"));
    lblCreateDate.Text = AutoDate;
    Label lblWebsite = ((Label)gvMainView.FooterRow.FindControl("lblWebsite"));
    lblWebsite.Text = Website;
}
```

**Edited**

I am no longer getting the "Object Reference" error however I am still unable to set the text of the labels dynamically.

Comment: is the grid bound on the page_load, maybe its still empty !!

Comment: I bound the gridview and the labels that I am trying to set are still blank...It does however get rid of the "object reference" error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Correct way to do it is After you bind the grid with data, Change the Label Text in the Prerender event like this:

```
protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      Label lblCreateDate = ((Label)gvMainView.FooterRow.FindControl("lblCreateDate")).Text;
    lblCreateDate.Text = AutoDate;
    Label lblWebsite = ((Label)gvMainView.FooterRow.FindControl("lblWebsite")).Text;
    lblWebsite.Text = Website;
}
```

the prerender is where you should always manipulate grid items before they get rendered to the user otherwise you'll have to reload things.